# Java. Хранится ли рефлексивная информация о классе в памяти JVM?

Tags: java, jvm, рефлексия

Вопрос в следующем, хранит ли JVM информацию о классе (например `Field[]`, `Method[]`, etc.) в памяти, после загрузки класса класслоадером и можно ли держать ссылки на эту информацию?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это зависит от того, какую JVM вы используете.

Например, у [Hotspot JVM](https://blogs.oracle.com/poonam/about-g1-garbage-collector,-permanent-generation-and-metaspace) в свежих версиях (8+) эта информация хранится в MetaSpace, который является частью native heap.

Держать ссылки на эту информацию можно, если она вам нужна. Если она не нужна, по идее лучше не держать, чтобы можно было выгрузить класс.

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понимаю вопрос, то да, jvm хранит мета-информацию о полях и методах классов в хипе.

Для Java до 7 версии в PermGen, для Java 8+ в MetaSpace.